# Unbiased estimate of mean test score of pupils in a country (sampling frame of schools is avaible only)

Tags: sampling, random-generation, survey-sampling, survey-weights

My primary goal is to get unbiased estimate of mean test score of every pupil in a country. I have no sampling frame of all pupils to randomly sample from. But I have a sampling frame for every school. When I choose a school from this sampling frame -> all pupils from this school are selected for a testing. Is it possible to estimate the mean score from such sample of pupils and extrapolate it to the whole population of pupils in a country?

My secondary goal is to get roughly proportional subgroups sizes of pupils from different type of schools (e.g. school can have different curriculum or is different in size etc.), and the sample may be not large enough, therefore I always end up with quite different proportions of those pupil in my final sample. Would weighting be sufficient correction for this difference?)

Comment: How do you propose to sample pupils when you have no information about them?

Comment: Thank you for this question. I add this information into original post: "Assume that when a school is chosen then all pupils from this school are selected into the sample."

Comment: Thank you.  Could you clarify what you mean by a "single random sample"?

Comment: Your question is baffling, because any random selection of schools automatically constitutes a random sample of pupils.  That's why it's crucial to explain precisely what you mean by "random sample."

Comment: I am trying to get the right formulation of this problem (as I see it as a problem), but it may be too difficult for me. But It may be more understandable in the opposite direction: My goal is to estimate mean test score of every pupil in a country -- is it sufficient for me to randomly sample (certain number of) schools in which those pupils study? (The problem is I can't sample pupils directly from sampling frame because I have only sampling frame of schools.)

Comment: Please rewrite your question to state your actual goal.  It begins to sound like you might need a hierarchical sample design, but you haven't yet given enough information to determine what you really need.

Comment: I tried to clarify the original question with respect to my primary and secondary goal.